# Ngrok forwarding fails when the index of the directory is a *.php file

Tags: php, xdebug, ngrok

I want to make ngrok work with a php script on my local server but after a bit of loading I get a 502 error:

> 502 Bad Gateway
>   The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

I've done the following - in my /etc/hosts there is a line

```
127.0.0.1   test.dev
```

Furthermore there is a virtual host enabled for that local domain:

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-test.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-test.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I put just a index.html file in my /var/www/test directory running

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite test.dev:80
```

works perfectly!

However if I rename index.html to index.php I get this loading error above.

I am using ngrok version 2.0.25 on Ubuntu 14.04.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind moving your solution to an answer? It'll help show that this question does have a solution.

Comment: @peter I've done it as a community answer.

Answer (score 0):

OP wrote in the question description:

> OK, the problem came from having had following setting enabled:
>
> ```
> xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
> ```
>
> After commenting it out ngrok started working also for *.php files.

Answer (score 0):

This was how I solved mine.
I browsed to the directory containing my app (where the index.php is) and I used cmd to start the server using:
`php -S localhost:4040`
After that, I executed the ngrok.exe file and run the command:
`ngrok http 4040`
And that solved my problem.